# brew command line mac is not working without following steps

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

i have to follow these steps every time: in order to use brew command in terminal,

- Add Homebrew to your PATH in /Users/$USER/.zprofile:

  ```
  echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile
  eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
  ```

3. Copy and paste the first line on the same terminal window, then hit enter

   ```
   echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile
   ```
4. Then Copy and paste the last line on the same terminal window, then hit enter

   ```
   eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
   [3:04 PM]
   ```

Is it possible to use brew command without these steps?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) or [Superuser](https://superuser.com) would be better places to ask about things like this.

Comment: But in the meantime: are you using the zsh shell (which those commands are indented for) or bash? Check with `ps $$`. In either case, don't keep running the `echo ...` command -- it adds a new line to your `.zprofile` each time, and for one reason or another that line isn't working and adding more of it isn't going to help. (In fact, at some point you should probably edit the `.zprofile` to remove the extras.) BTW, I edited the question to use code block format, but I'm not sure I got it right. What is the `[3:04 PM]` supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below steps to solve this issue:

1. brew install eval
2. echo 'eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)' >> /Users/$USER/.zprofile
   eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
3. eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)

This should work.

Comment: im using mac m1, even after the above steps i need to follow the steps to use brew command after opening a new terminal